# "Replace Image" or "Swap Image," which is better to use?

Tags: text, image

My coworker and I are wondering which is more appropriate to use: replace image or swap image.

I'm rooting for replace, which I think sounds more professional. However, my coworker makes a very good point. He believes that replace has a negative connotation to it. You only replace something when it's broken or gone bad.

Thoughts?

Comment: Don't people also swap things because it is not what they want? It feels like replacement is to exchange one thing or another that is similar, while swap doesn't necessarily have any bearings on what you are swapping it with.

Comment: I think this question might be more appropriate for http://english.stackexchange.com/ because it's about interpretation of a word by a more general audience. (apparently I can't vote to move to that site, only to meta - not sure if this is a bug)

Comment: I don't see this negative connotation to "replace".

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question, it seems like a case where you just want to provide the user the ability to update or change the image. My suggestion would be to just do use the terminology which depicts what you want the user to do ie. "**Update Image**" or "**Change Image**"

For example Twitter uses the word "**Change**"

[image]

while facebook uses the word "**Update**" while updating the facebook profile picture or the cover photograph

[image]